# wordpress home page use from different directory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have wordpress installed on my root folder directory files are like public_html/wp-admin, public_html/wp-content etc..

I want it when my site "www.example.com" is visited it will read another folder in the subdirectory eg (public_html/showhomepage)

where showhomepage has a static index.html with css, images etc

Is this possible?

Comment: This is a server configuration issue, not an *.htaccess*, php, or WordPress issue

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress/index.php:

```
header('Location: showhomepage');
```

Or you can set up a rewrite rule in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . /showhomepage [L]
```

Or something along those lines. Apache has good on [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and there's plenty of supporting sites to make some of the explanations more clear.

I may be mistaken but, that redirects requests to your site to showhomepage. I'm not an expert at rewrite rules but I think you can suppress the path with REQUEST_FILENAME in your rewrite conditions.

Comment: but this would change my url right? it would not be www.example.com anymore

Comment: In that case use .htaccess to set up a rewrite rule that does just that